# How do I iterate a button that will trigger a modal popup using PHP while statement

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a system that gets user data from a mysql database using PHP. The "while" statement shows the results from the database table. I want to be able to add a skill for each user in the database. I have a button that when clicked, triggers a modal popup with the user name and id.   I am failing to get iterated buttons to trigger a modal popup. Only the button from the first row works.(Please forgive my English). How do i get all buttons to trigger a modal popup form that will show the respective user name and id?

Html and PHP

```
  <table id="proj" border="0" width = "85%">
  <tr >
    <td width = "30%" align = "center">User ID</td>
    <td  width = "30%" align = "center">Name</td>
    <td align = "center">Actions</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--rows containing stuff from database-->
<?php

include 'dbcon.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = $con->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
    <div class="prows">
      <div class="prow" align = "center">
        <div class="id1">
          <?php echo $row["id"]; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="status1">
          <?php  echo $row["name"]; ?>
        </div>
      <div class="pm1">
        <button id="bnUpdt">Add Skill</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2 style="display:inline-block; margin-right:100px;">Name: <?php  echo $row["name"]; ?></h2>
      <p style="display:inline-block;margin-right:100px;">User ID: <?php echo $row["id"]; ?></p>
    </div>
    <form action="update.php" method="post" class="modal-body" align="center">
      <div class="task" >
        <input type="text" name="task" >
        <button type="submit" name="button"> Add</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
   <?php
  }
}
?>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("bnUpdt");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
    btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

CSS

```
<style media="screen">

.pm1, .id1, .status1{
 display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
 }
#sel{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 10%;

}
.prows{
 width:80%;
 }
.prow{
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ededed;
  color:#424242;
}
.prow:hover{
  background-color: #e3c7a8;

}
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
   position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
 }

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
 position: relative;
 background-color: #fefefe;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0;
 border: 1px solid #888;
 width: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
 from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
 to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
 to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

 /* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
 padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #42350f;
  color: white;
}

 .modal-body {padding: 20px;}

</style>
```

I would like to get each button in each row to trigger a modal popup

Comment: I don't think you can have multiple html items with the same id.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by ryantxr, you can't have multiple IDs with same name. Add a classname and loop through them instead. Something like this perhaps? Assuming you have added class="bnUpdate" to the necessary elements.

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('bnUpdt');
for(var i=0; i<elem.length; i++) {
  elem[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        // add skill code...
  });
}
```

Hope it helps.